# Any good usable software or software package for decomposition with constraint?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, math-software, sum-of-squares-method, real-algebraic-geometry

Does anyone know any good and usable software package, preferably in Windows, that can effectively find SOS (sum of squares) polynomials $s_{0}\left(x\right)$
and $s_{1}\left(x\right)$ for any real polynomial $f\left(x\right)\ge0$
on $\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}:g\left(x\right)\ge0\right\} $ where
$g\left(x\right)$ is a real polynomial, such that
$$
f\left(x\right)=s_{1}\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)+s_{0}\left(x\right)?
$$
Many thanks.

Comment: YALMIP is great if you have Matlab

Comment: @LinAlg  Thank you for your comment. But can YALMIP do EXACT decomposition (or find the EXACT polynomials that are SOS (sum of squares) for the decomposition)? Thanks.